# How to get attributes for tags as key and value from xml using php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have to convert array to xml using php.

Below is my xml,

```
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute dt:dt="int" name="Attr_New">0</custom-attribute>
  <custom-attribute dt:dt="date" name="Attr_New_Date">20150601</custom-attribute>
  <custom-attribute dt:dt="string" name="Attr_Base_SKU">314100822304</custom-attribute>
```

I want output like below,

```
[custom-attribute] => Array
(
    [Attr_New] => 0
    [Attr_New_Date] => 20150601
    [Attr_Base_SKU] => 314100822304
)
```

But Iam getting like below,

```
[custom-attribute] => Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 20150601
    [2] => 314100822304
)
```

Please help me someone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Comment: You have to get the "name" attribute from the tags. I don't know if you're using DOM or SimpleXML - but both have methods for. Then you'll have 2 arrays - one with the names and one with the values. Then you can use array_combine to get the result: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php